# export data from dynamic xml in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis, export

I have the following table, and for each row there is a different xml with different fields: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW3Ij.png)

I want to get data from xml by the values I get in the fields: VsDateField, ProfField, VsKeyField
(The values can be different in every row)

I try to write a dynamic expression for reading from xml file:

```sql
PATDATA.value('(/rc0004//'+VsDateField+'/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

but I received the following error message:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

How can I get data from dynamic xml that the fields are changed too?

Comment: Sample data and the desired result would help.

Comment: `patdata.value('(rc004/*[local-name() = sql:column("vsdatefield")]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') `